# How to compare 2 object in react JS and get the values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I have 2 state

```
 console.log(this.state.tempWilayahUser)
 console.log(this.state.wilayahUser)
```

how to get row when have same value of id_rt ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` function to achieve this. You can read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here.

```
const state1 = [];
const state2 = [];

const itemsWithIdRtFromState1 = state1.filter(item1 => {
    return state2.filter(item2 => item2?.id_rt === item1?.id_rt)
});

const itemsWithIdRtFromState2 = state2.filter(item2 => {
    return state1.filter(item1 => item1?.id_rt === item2?.id_rt)
});
```